# CSS style Woocommerce Single Product page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making a webshop with the plugin Woocommerce.

What I'm doing now is styling the single product page for my site. I already changed the order of the hooks. So "related products" is now above the tab screens. But it's way too high. I tried to change it with a div around it. But that doesn't work.

Photo of my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhVO0.jpg

The code:

```
<div class="related">
<?php
    /**
    * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
    * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
?>
</div>
<meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
```

CSS i already tried:

```
.related {
   top: 40px;
   margin-top: 40px;
   padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

All of this doesn't work. Anyone knows how to get related products lower?

Comment: PHP is of very little use here. Output HTML is required

Comment: This is all I got, what do you need more?

Comment: I think I was pretty clear.  Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: But I gave the code I'm working with, an example of my problem and described the problem.

Comment: Yes, but the title "gerelateerde producten" doesn't move with it. So the related products is now lower, but the "gerelateerde producten" header is at the same place.

Comment: It's because you may have override some html tags in woocommerce templates or you may have set some inappropriate CSS rules to main related products html block

Comment: okay, but where can I find the related products html block.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `<div class="related">` in **content-single-product.php** template. Please remove it as before.
Why? Because the class `related` is already used in **single-product > related.php** template with:
 `<div class="related products">` html tag in it.

What you can do is to add some space after tabs withs this CSS rule:

```
div.woocommerce-tabs.wc-tabs-wrapper {
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

When you want to overlap an existing defined CSS rule on wooCommerce pages, sometimes you need to add at the end of a CSS value attribute `!important`. The best thing is to test a CSS rule without first and if needed with it as this:

```
div.woocommerce-tabs.wc-tabs-wrapper {
    padding-bottom:40px !important;
}
```

**---- (Edit) ----**

Here is the CSS rule you asked last (try also without `!important` first):

```
.woocommerce .products.related ul.products {
    padding-top:40px !important;
}
```

you can try too:

```
.woocommerce .products.related ul.products {
    margin-top:40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works. But I need to change the padding-top of my related products, not the tabs wrapper.

Comment: I will do that. But i demonstrated the problem with the photo. ;-)

Comment: But what HTML output do you need?

Comment: Here is a link. Problem is that "gerelateerde producten" is too high.

Answer (score 1):

you need dot "." operator to specify the CSS class selector & hash "#" for id selector, try this code.

```
.related {
   margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
```

Cheers

Comment: oh sorry, the dot was fallen away when copying the code to this question.

Comment: Did you try to give the !important tag? And remove the top property, you don't need that.

Comment: Yes, i did it and that doesn't work. Still the same as before.