# Style WooCommerce Single Product Summary in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

So i have the product page in WooCommerce and im trying to style the individual parts inside the product summary. I have no idea how to do it.

These are the divs i wrote originally to visualize and style the necessary functions:

```
<!--
    <div class="Product_category">T-Shirts</div>
    <div class="Product_title">Product Name</div>
       <div class="Product_hr"></div>
    <div class="Product_modelNumber">CATG-1000-0001</div>
    <div class="Product_Price">$99<sup>.00</sup></div>
    <div class="Product_size_container">
        <div class="Product_size" style="margin-left: 4px">XS</div>
        <div class="Product_size">S</div>
        <div class="Product_size">M</div>
        <div class="Product_size">L</div>
        <div class="Product_size">XL</div>
        <div class="Product_size">XXL</div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div> 

    <div class="Product_Addtocart">Add to Cart</div>
-->
```

I am in the content-single-product.php in my child theme and understand at least that i have to edit this bit of code here:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','' );

        ?>
    </div>
```

Basically, id like to put my css styles around the corresponding snippets. I just would like to know how to do it.

Every tutorial i come across only shows how to arrange product order but gives me nothing on the styling, which is all i care about. How do i attack this?

Comment: If you only need to style the elements, why don't you inspect those elements and overwrite the styles in your style.css?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843725/css-style-woocommerce-single-product-page

Comment: There are some parts id like to move around, order wise, subtract and add as well. Plus i know there is a way to encapsulate my snippets with the appropriate css so I'm trying to learn how exactly to do it the right way

Comment: You can use Hooks to move stuff around and also wrap elements in containers. [see here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/).

Comment: i already saw this sir. I was asking for a more specific example to my question. i saw that page before i even came here. He doesn't say anything at all pertaining to the css on that page or website. im looking to execute the hooks and the css combined in the same code snippets